# html spotlight for multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, typescript

I have an html page, which contains lots of elements like `div`'s or `li`'s and their positions are diffuse on the page not regularly. I want to make dark zones outside of these elements as in the image I added. The image below explains my issue:

[image]

I want to create elements for gray area in the image  multifactorial so I can change these elements css style. 
I thought this way the best solution to create dark zones for outside of these html elements.

[image]

Comment: So you want a border around the divs and list items?

Comment: ...or more like darken the rest of the page?